# remove milliseconds from datetime type

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime-format

Trying to remove the milliseconds and the pm/am from the datetime field using Oracle SQL.

My query is:

```
select created_dt from mydatabase
```

Output is:

```
09-NOV-21 12.18.40.490000000 PM
```

I tried using `to_char(created_dt, 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss')` then using `to_timestamp` to convert back to datetime type but the milliseconds showing again.

Comment: Oracle does not have a "datetime" data type. It has the "date" data type, which (contrary to its name) includes both "date" and "time-of-day" components. But what you have is different: it's a **timestamp**, not a "date" ("datetime"). In any case - are you just asking about how to **display** it in the required format? You can't force Oracle to not include fractional seconds in a timestamp; if you need that (at the data level), then `created_dt` is in the wrong data type.

Answer (score 1):

A `TIMESTAMP` data type is stored in a table as a binary data-type with 1-byte for each of century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second and has up to 6 bytes for fractional seconds. It is **NEVER** stored with any particular format.

If you want to change the number of fractional digits in a timestamp then you need to use `CAST`:

```sql
SELECT CAST(created_dt AS TIMESTAMP(0))
FROM   mydatabase
```

However, you could just convert it to a `DATE` (which also has year-to-second components but no fractional seconds):

```sql
SELECT CAST(created_dt AS DATE)
FROM   mydatabase
```

Once you have done that then whatever client application you are using (SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, Java, C#, PHP, etc.) will still use its default rules for displaying the `TIMESTAMP` (or `DATE`) and those rules may display a certain number of fractional seconds.

If you are using SQL/Plus or SQL Developer (but not if you are using Java, C#, PHP, etc.) then the default format is controlled by the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter.

You can alter this using:

```
-- Display with precision of the data type
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF';
-- Display with 6-digits precision
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6';
-- Display with no fractional seconds.
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

But, if you want a consistent method of formatting a `TIMESTAMP` then use `TO_CHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

How the DATE or TIMESTAMP data types are stored can't be changed.

But you can change how a query outputs a TIMESTAMP by default for the session.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

Example:

> ```
> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS';
>
> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
> ```

> ```
> select ts
> , CAST(ts AS DATE) dt
> , CAST(ts AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) AS tstz
> from
> (
>   select 
>    to_timestamp('2021-11-30 23:30:45.123456789', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') AS ts     
>   from dual
> ) q
> ```
>
> ```
> TS                  | DT                   | TSTZ                            
> :------------------ | :------------------- | :-------------------------------
> 2021-11-30 23:30:45 | 2021-NOV-30 23:30:45 | 30-NOV-21 23.30.45.123457 +00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fdaccc9716f8655780408cdd3dba37b3)*